# Methods of accounting for static lighting contributions on dynamic objects

Tags: opengl, graphics, lighting

Currently, I am working on precomputing static lighting for a small graphics engine.

Here is my current workflow:

- Objects and Lights have a mobility tag (either static or dynamic)
- Prior to rendering, lightmaps are computed for static lights and static objects.
- Dynamic lighting calculations are done using a deferred shading model.
- Static objects apply their lightmaps during the geometry pass.

The problem is as follows:

Ideally, static lights will also light dynamic objects and dynamic lights will light static objects (all in the deferred shader). The issue is that static lighting contributions on static objects will be "double counted" in the deferred shader, i.e. static lights will light objects that have already been lit by those lights. What are some methods of accounting for this?

Here are some of the ideas that I have had; however, all of these are not ideal:

- Make static lights not light dynamic objects (or the opposite: make dynamic lights not light static objects).

  - This would probably be my last choice of a solution.
- Pass the mobility tag for each light to the deferred shader as well as make the mobility tag part of the gbuffer.

  - I don't really want to add another render target for the mobility tag (I am already using 4 for PBR!).
- Get rid of precomputed lightmaps for static geometry altogether?

  - I don't really want to do this either.

Are there any other possible solutions to this issue?

Comment: Do you precompute a separate lightmap for every object for every light? Would it not be possible to precompute just a lightmap for the static lighting contributions on every static object and then draw those in a separate pass?

Comment: I precompute one lightmap for each object.  Every static light adds its contribution to these lightmaps.  It wouldn't really be feasible to draw the static objects in another pass I don't think. That would require doing the deferred shading pass, then clearing the gbuffer, performing another geometry pass, then yet another deferred shading pass. Or I could forward render the static objects in another pass, but this eliminates the benefits of deferred rendering (there are potentially very many static objects and dynamic lights).

Comment: So If I understand correctly, then you already have to draw all the geometry to the gbuffer because static objects may be lit by dynamic lights. And you already have to draw all the lights during deferred shading because dynamic objects may be lit by static lights. So if you're already having to draw all the geometry and all the lights, then where exactly do you see lightmaps saving you computation?

Comment: If you insist on drawing the static light on static objects as part of the deferred shading pass rather than a separate forward pass, then you will necessarily have to somehow distinguish between the two cases during deferred shading. There is no general answer to whether this is worth it or not. Your shading model may very well be so expensive that skipping some lights for some fragments in exchange for a texture lookup plus the overhead for separate treatment is worth it. It may be that your vertex processing is so costly that you can't do it twice. All highly depends on your application…

Comment: I wasn't looking for a general answer, just some possible solutions (although I realize it is highly dependent on my application). The precomputed lightmaps store more information than just the regular static lighting (I'm also precomputing indirect lighting using photon mapping). I may have to just write the mobility tag to the gbuffer.

Comment: The only way to really find out what's best for your application is to benchmark. But if the deferred shading is already handling the direct lighting from static lights on static objects at sufficient performance, then I don't see why bother with the lightmaps. If you want the lightmaps for the ability to do fancy precomputed illumination (something you maybe should have mentioned in your question), then I'd probably consider having, e.g., just the indirect component in the lightmaps and drawing just that as a separate pass…

Comment: Yea that was another thing I was considering. I think you are correct in that deferred shading can handle static lighting without a performance hit.

Comment: Well, the question really comes down to whether the cost of just computing the shading for static lights on static objects anyways will be higher than the overhead introduced by the facilities necessary to skip those computations and replace them with a lookup of the precomputed result. Again, only benchmarking can really answer that, but I would say chances are that the simpler solution is gonna be at least just fine…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: you can use a single GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 target for your depth and stencil buffers, then pass the dynamic/static flag through the stencil buffer.